# Spam notification keeps appearing

Tags: notifications

the following notification keeps appearing every day. Is there any way I can turn it off? The app is safe and not sure why it's notifying me at all. I have a Moto G 2015 with rooted CM14.1.
[image: Spam notification]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This activity is controlled by the "Verify Apps" part of settings for Google.

From the device, select

> Settings > Google > Security > Verify Apps > "Scan device"

, and turn it OFF.